# Delphi Chromium Embedded - File download

Tags: delphi, download, chromium-embedded

I am using Delphi Chromium Embedded in my application, and I have the following problem.
In a Web Application that must be loaded in the Application I am developing with Delphi Chromium Embedded there is a command to download remote file from server.
This command works when I use it from Chrome browser, but when I try to do the same from Delphi Chromium Embedded it doesn't work, and there's no error displayed in Developers Tools console.
Is there some configuration in DCEF to enable download ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the "Developer Tools" console. This is a window inside the Chrome/Chromium framework? How about Return values from the functions you called?  Can you post a short code snippet?

Comment: @Warren, it's the same console as you can see if you press F12 in Chrome browser.

Comment: Yes, it is so. The code of HTML/Javascript is a little complicated, is written in ExtJS... in any case it works good in browser, but in Chromium Embedded it does nothing, no file downloaded and no error...

Comment: So it's javascript code that executes. Can you single step debug that javascript code somehow while running DCEF?